# omnifaces genericEnumConverter and enum properties

Tags: jsf, enums, converters, omnifaces

I am using omnifaces 1.7-snapshot genericEnumConverter. It works as expected. I would like to know if it is possible on the item label to show an enum property instead of its value. I was only able to render the enum itself. Like this:

```
public enum ErrorType {
    ERR_001, ERR_002, ERR_003;

    private String number;

    static {
        ERR_001.number = "001";
        ERR_002.number = "002";
        ERR_003.number = "003";
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}

<f:selectItems value="#{ErrorType}" var="er" itemLabel="#{er.number}" itemValue="#{er}" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gather that you're using [`<o:importConstants>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/importConstants) for the `<f:selectItems value>`? The `GenericEnumConverter` isn't taking care of this. It plays only a role on converting between the select item value and the component's value. It doesn't play any role on displaying the item labels.

The `<o:importConstants>` basically makes the enum values available in EL scope as a `Map<String, Enum>`. Although the `<f:selectItems>` can take a `Map<K, V>`, it however doesn't support iterating over a `Map<K, V>` by `var`. You need to convert it to a `Map.Entry[]` first:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{ErrorType.entrySet().toArray()}" var="er" 
    itemValue="#{er.value}" itemLabel="#{er.value.number}"/>
```